# Ruby and Rails or Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand Rails is a web framework built on Ruby. Ruby is a language separate from Rails which Rails uses. I'm not getting if it is best to use both separately or it is best to use Ruby on Rails.

Or is Ruby on Rails a completely different framework just using Ruby code and Rails code? Could you just install both Ruby and Rails and set them both up together?
If the above is true then what is Ruby on Rails and the benefits of using it in comparison to setting up Ruby and Rails as one?

Comment: See meaning #2 of http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name "Ruby on Rails" is sometimes shortened as "Rails", or "RoR", which is the same - a web development framework.

You can, of course, use *Ruby* without *Rails*, as you can use any other programming language, to build different programs, not only web applications.

You cannot use *Rails* without using *Ruby*, because as you wrote yourself, *Rails* is a web framework built in Ruby. When you build web applications in *Rails*, you write your code in the *Ruby* language (there are some other rewrites of *Rails*, like *GRails*, which uses *Groovy*, but this is a different thing).

If you follow the installation guide on the [Get Started](http://rubyonrails.org/download) page, you will see that you first install *Ruby* for your platform, then install *RubyGems* (which is a package manager for installing additional Ruby libraries), and then use *RubyGems* `gem install rails` command to install *Rails* with all its dependencies. So you might say that *Rails* is a library for *Ruby*.

This installation of *Rails* then provides a set of scripts, including the `rails` command, which help you build your web application according to the set of conventions adopted by *Rails*.

Comment: So by installing both ruby and rails separately like you suggested this is now Ruby on Rails or to use Ruby on Rails you need to install another package.

Comment: Yes, installing it separately means you now have Ruby on Rails. I agree the name may be a bit confusing, because you might say it's actually Rails on Ruby :). Anyway, "Ruby on Rails" is just a name.

Comment: it's a pun... referencing the convention over configuration approach to rails.

Answer (score 3):

RUBY => programming language

RUBY ON RAILS => web framework written in ruby

ROR / RAILS => shortcut for RUBY ON RAILS

is this still confusing?

Answer (score 1):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html:

> Rails is a web application framework running on the Ruby programming language.

I highly recommend making your way through this guide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems many people don't know Ruby but they know Rails. Just as much as I know how to use JQuery without actually understanding JavaScript. So you're not completely off the trail asking this question :)

But honestly, it's not much fun just doing Rails without understanding Ruby. As soon as you understand Ruby you will see more to it than just Rails.

I'd recommend you get familiar with Ruby first and then see if you like the language. If you do you can go further and try Rails as well. If Ruby doesn't suit your language tastes try a different language like Java or Erlang or Python (whatever, doesn't really matter and - as always- depends on the problem you're trying to solve).

If you like Ruby you will also soon learn that there are other nice web frameworks like Sinatra that are a lot smaller and might fit your needs a lot better. Again, it depends on your needs.

Read up on some of the languages, mostly their web sites offer some insight into what they are like and what they are good for. Check http://ruby-lang.org for Ruby!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is web development framework built using Ruby. So it borrows the syntax and some functionality. Ruby is programming language and it is not specific to domain. Ruby can be used in more than one domain. If you want to develop a web app you need to use Ruby on Rails. There are many web frameworks built on Ruby.

For knowing Rails you need to know basics of Ruby. So better to start Ruby first. Once you get the basics you can learn both parallel.

For Ruby refer: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

For RoR refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Use RVM (Ruby Version Manager): to install. Link: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is an a language, and Ruby on Rails is an a webframework. It is more like C# and ASP.NET, Python and Django or Java and Spring. So everything what is possible with Ruby is posible with Rails and the other way, everything what is possible in Rails is possible in Ruby, but it can be harder, longer or less clear than using RoR.